# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild'), Discord.JS v14, NodeJS 16

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Console errors with error in title, command code below (getnews.js)

```js
import { SlashCommandBuilder, Client, } from 'discord.js';
const client = Client
const message = client.msg

// Creates an Object in JSON with the data required by Discord's API to create a SlashCommand
const create = () => {
    const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('getnews')
        .setDescription('Assigns role for bot news.')

    return command.toJSON();
};

// Called by the interactionCreate event listener when the corresponding command is invoked
const invoke = (interaction) => {
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bot News");
    let member = message.member
    member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
};

export { create, invoke };
```

What i did: Tried to make it so that when you run a command it grants you a role.

Result: Bot just crashes with the error in title.

detailed error:

```
Successfully logged in as user#tag
file:///C:/Users/Logan/Documents/harrisbot2.0/events/commands/getnews.js:16
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bot News");
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')
    at Module.invoke (file:///C:/Users/Logan/Documents/harrisbot2.0/events/commands/getnews.js:16:21)
    at Module.invoke (file:///C:/Users/Logan/Documents/harrisbot2.0/events/interactionCreate.js:8:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)What
```

Comment: What does `const client = Client; const message = client.msg;` supposed to do?

Comment: The ``` const client= Client; ``` just makes it so if i don't capitalize the "c" in client it works & ``` const message = client.msg ``` I'm not sure but I think message doesn't exist, it was some code that I looked up before, I'll test with those removed.

Comment: ` let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bot News");
 Reference error: message is not defined `

Comment: Maybe I need to import message with discord.js? Or something to do with guilds?

Comment: Right, I've imported stuff but now it says ` let role = Message.Guild.Roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bot News");
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Roles') `

I've tried ".roles" and ".Roles", and importing roles with discord.js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Client` you imported from `discord.js` doesn't have an exported property called `msg`. According to you, this function will be run by the `interactionCreate` event listener, and so you will have an interaction. Then, the best way for you to find roles, add roles, send messages etc., would be to use the interaction itself instead of a `message`. Your fixed code would look like this:

```js
import { SlashCommandBuilder, Client } from 'discord.js';

const create = () => {
    const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('getnews')
        .setDescription('Assigns role for bot news.')

    return command.toJSON();
};

const invoke = async (interaction) => {
    await interaction.guild.roles.fetch()
    let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bot News");
    let member = interaction.member
    member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
};

export { create, invoke };
```

(Note: With `.cache.find()`, sometimes the value might not be there in the cache, which is why I added the `.fetch()` before.)

Comment: I'll try this now, I'll let you know if it works, thanks!